Are reset gates allowed on IBM quantum computers?
My circuit involves many "reset" gates. After running on the IBM real backend, the experiment status says "Failed" with error message that says:

Failed - Unknown operation type for DAGOpNode(op=Instruction(name='reset', num_qubits=1, num_clbits=0, params=[]), qargs=(Qubit(QuantumRegister(127, 'q'), 45),), cargs=()). -- Verify the input circuits and the traspilation options. -- https://ibm.biz/error_codes#1516

I have already used the latest "Transpile" instruction to make the circuit fit the real backends:
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
backend = service.backend("ibm_kyoto")
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
isa_qcs = pm.run(circuit)

From the qiskit website, the lines above seems to be the standard way to pass a circuit to a real backend. Doesn't the pass manager turn my original circuit into something the real backend can implement? Am I missing something? Is the error I am receiving due to A: I have not done the transpilation correctly? OR B: Reset is completely not allowed on a real backend?(By the way, the circuit runs correctly using simulators.)
Any advice or insights are welcome!

Can you also provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can try by ourselves?
